# Google Play Games C++ SDK v3.0 not a drop in replacement?

Tags: android-ndk, google-play-games

I have been using the C++ SDK of Google Play Games: `gpg_cpp_sdk.v2.3.zip`

I have now downloaded the new version `gpg_cpp_sdk.v3.0.zip` as [available](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks) from Google.

Whereas the 2.3 version would work just fine, during build, and during runtime, I have not been able to link against the 3.0 version.

I get this error:

```
  [178/178] : && /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -marm -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -DANDROID=1 -DPLAY=1 -DUSEES2=1 -DLOGTAG=swaag -DAPPVER=4.40 -DDEBUG -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libbuggy.so -o /home/bram/apps/Buggy/AndroidStudio/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libbuggy.so CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/StateManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/leaderboardmanager.cpp.o  /home/bram/src/gpg-cpp-sdk_3.0/android/lib/gnustl/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.a pi/libpi.a gbase/libgbase.a opende/libopende.a gpgoap/libgpgoap.a ip2ensign/libip2ensign.a -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES -landroid -llog -lz -lm -latomic -lm "/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
  FAILED: : && /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 --sysroot=/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -marm -mfpu=neon -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -std=c++11 -DANDROID=1 -DPLAY=1 -DUSEES2=1 -DLOGTAG=swaag -DAPPVER=4.40 -DDEBUG -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot /home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-16/arch-arm -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libbuggy.so -o /home/bram/apps/Buggy/AndroidStudio/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libbuggy.so CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/StateManager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/buggy.dir/leaderboardmanager.cpp.o  /home/bram/src/gpg-cpp-sdk_3.0/android/lib/gnustl/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.a pi/libpi.a gbase/libgbase.a opende/libopende.a gpgoap/libgpgoap.a ip2ensign/libip2ensign.a -lEGL -lGLESv2 -lOpenSLES -landroid -llog -lz -lm -latomic -lm "/home/bram/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a" && :
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:137: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::AchievementManager::Unlock(std::string const&)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:145: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::AchievementManager::SetStepsAtLeast(std::string const&, unsigned int)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:153: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::LeaderboardManager::SubmitScore(std::string const&, unsigned long long)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:161: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::AchievementManager::ShowAllUI(std::function<void (gpg::UIStatus const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:175: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::LeaderboardManager::ShowAllUI(std::function<void (gpg::UIStatus const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:193: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScoreSummary(gpg::DataSource, std::string const&, gpg::LeaderboardTimeSpan, gpg::LeaderboardCollection, std::function<void (gpg::LeaderboardManager::FetchScoreSummaryResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:270: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::AchievementManager::FetchAll(std::function<void (gpg::AchievementManager::FetchAllResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:339: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::SendUnreliableMessageToOthers(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:345: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::SendReliableMessage(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, gpg::MultiplayerParticipant const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, std::function<void (gpg::MultiplayerStatus const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:430: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::PlayerManager::Fetch(std::string const&, std::function<void (gpg::PlayerManager::FetchResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:452: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::PlayerManager::FetchConnected(std::function<void (gpg::PlayerManager::FetchListResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:681: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::CreateRealTimeRoom(gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig const&, gpg::IRealTimeEventListener*, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:708: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowRoomInboxUI(std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RoomInboxUIResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:723: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowPlayerSelectUI(unsigned int, unsigned int, bool, std::function<void (gpg::TurnBasedMultiplayerManager::PlayerSelectUIResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:730: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::LeaveRoom(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, std::function<void (gpg::ResponseStatus const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:790: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::GameServices::Builder::SetOnAuthActionStarted(std::function<void (gpg::AuthOperation)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:791: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::GameServices::Builder::SetOnAuthActionFinished(std::function<void (gpg::AuthOperation, gpg::AuthStatus)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:792: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::GameServices::Builder::SetOnMultiplayerInvitationEvent(std::function<void (gpg::MultiplayerEvent, std::string, gpg::MultiplayerInvitation)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:619: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowWaitingRoomUI(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, unsigned int, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::WaitingRoomUIResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:594: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::AcceptInvitation(gpg::MultiplayerInvitation const&, gpg::IRealTimeEventListener*, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:538: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowWaitingRoomUI(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, unsigned int, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::WaitingRoomUIResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:648: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::CreateRealTimeRoom(gpg::RealTimeRoomConfig const&, gpg::IRealTimeEventListener*, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:779: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::PlayerManager::FetchSelf(std::function<void (gpg::PlayerManager::FetchSelfResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:561: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowWaitingRoomUI(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, unsigned int, std::function<void (gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::WaitingRoomUIResponse const&)>)'
  /home/bram/apps/Buggy/Android/jni/StateManager.cpp:567: error: undefined reference to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::LeaveRoom(gpg::RealTimeRoom const&, std::function<void (gpg::ResponseStatus const&)>)'
  /home/bram/src/gpg-cpp-sdk_3.0/android/lib/gnustl/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.a:third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:function gpg::AndroidGameServicesImpl::AchievementFetchAllOperation::AchievementFetchAllOperation(std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<gpg::AndroidGameServicesImpl>, gpg::InternalCallback<gpg::AchievementManager::FetchAllResponse const&>, gpg::DataSource): error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()'
  /home/bram/src/gpg-cpp-sdk_3.0/android/lib/gnustl/armeabi-v7a/libgpg.a:third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc:function gpg::AndroidGameServicesImpl::AndroidFetcherOperation<gpg::AchievementManager::FetchAllResponse>::AndroidFetcherOperation(std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<gpg::AndroidGameServicesImpl>, gpg::InternalCallback<gpg::AchievementManager::FetchAllResponse const&>): error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::__shared_weak_count::__add_shared()'
...
```

This is in my CMakeLists.txt and used to work:

```
add_library( gpg
             STATIC
             IMPORTED
)
set_target_properties( gpg
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        $ENV{HOME}/src/gpg-cpp-sdk_3.0/android/lib/gnustl/${ANDROID_ABI}/libgpg.a
)
```

It seems that v3.0 is not a drop-in replacement for the v2.3 library.
Is there anything I should do differently with the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem problem replacing older SDK with v3.0 and decided to stick with v2.3 because of first requirement for v3.0:

> Requires Android NDK r14 or higher.

check if you meet all of the requirements listed in v3.0 [release notes](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/releaseNotes)

I wasted a lot of time before i checked this myself.

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete solution.